# Query with two conditions in web2py and SQLFORM.grid

Tags: sql, web2py

I am using a web2py SQLFORM.grid to show a table named db.Essen, which works perfectly.
Now I want to filter entries using a query, which again works well as follows:

```
 Query = db.Essen.Datum == '2018-12-03'
 grid = SQLFORM.grid(Query)
```

However, I run into problems when trying to combine two conditions in a query such as:

```
 Query = ((db.Essen.Datum == '2018-12-03') or (db.Essen.Datum == '2018-12-04'))
 grid = SQLFORM.grid(Query)
```

It seems that only the first condition gets executed, the second condition is simply ignored.

How can I implement queries with two conditions in SQLFORM.grid?

Comment: I think that you just want an OR condition instead of AND : (db.Essen.Datum == '2018-12-03') or (db.Essen.Datum == '2018-12-04')

Comment: @GMB :-) You are correct, but this was only a typo which originated from simplifying the example. It does not work with 'or' either, but each single conditions works when I delete the other. In the result, only the first condition is shown as query: Query: 
`<Query ("Essen"."Datum" = '2018-12-03')>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `|` for an "or" query (and `&` for an "and" query):

```
(db.Essen.Datum == '2018-12-03') | (db.Essen.Datum == '2018-12-04')
```

See http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Logical-operators.